# Install ubuntu-extras on debian wheezy

Tags: linux, flash, debian

I've been  trying to install packages like ubuntu-extras on my recently installed debian wheezy.

So I've added the line `deb http://deb-multimedia.org wheezy main non-free` (which is the new url for debian-multimedia) to my source list, but when i try the `apt-get update` it says that the url public key is not available No_PUBKEY .

How could I soplve this problem and install all the things like flash, java etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a key at the end of the error message like this:

> W: GPG error: ftp://ftp.fr.debian.org testing Release:  The following
>   signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not
>   available: NO_PUBKEY **xxxxxxxxxxxxxx**

Replace the xxxx with it:

```
 gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 gpg -a --export xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx| sudo apt-key add -
```